# User File Upload Repository?

Tags: users, uploads, repository

I am trying to make a user-uploaded file repository on my wordpress site, but have been unable to find any plug-ins or tutorials on how to accomplish such a task. Basically I want a page where users can go and upload files via an upload file dialogue. Then I want to have a page that lists all user-submitted files that is sortable.  I have seen some tutorials on how to add an upload option to a users dashboard, but I'm not using the normal dashboard because I think it is clunky.

Are there any such plug-ins out there? Or does anyone have any recommendations?

Thanks,

Tre!

Comment: I'm taking a look at http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-images-your-site/ to see if I can accomplish something similar, though I got a script error with the source code. If anyone knows any other resources, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are plugins that will let you do this.
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-files/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-filebase/
Whatever you decide though keep in mind security when doing things like this. You don't want people going crazy and uploading huge files either, so check the plugins have built in restrictions on what can be uploaded and that they are in active development.